# Getting the >> icon ("show more" ) behavior in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to implement Bookmark or Favorite Bar just below a Toolbar. The result should be similar to the interface in the Dictionary Application. Seemingly there is not standard component for doing this (corrections are welcome).
I could use something like the MGScopeBar and play around with till I get something similar.
Is there a better/simpler approach to achieve exactly the behavior? Especially stuff like the >> icon on the right, is there some component that already implements this behavior? If not, what is the name of the >> icon ("show more" ) or where do I find it? I had a glance at INAppStoreWindow as well but it did not seem to have this "show more" feature.

Comment: NSToolbar should do this automatically when it runs out of space.

Comment: @CodaFi: But that doesn't help for something just below a toolbar.

Comment: It's generally called a chevron. The petroleum company has one as its logo, albeit oriented differently.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using MGScopeBar, stripping it down and adapting it to my needs needs. For the >> symbol, I created my own with Art Text 2 Lite, by using two > and modifying them.
I just somehow expected that Scopebar existed as object to choose in Interface Builder, especially since OS X Interface Guidelines talks at one point about “Using a Scope Bar to Enable Searching and Filtering”.

Just in case somebody needs something similar, drop me line as I am willing to share, although it probably still could need improvements.